# Query optimization with conditional group by and where

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have a DB with events, workshops in each event (1:N), participants in each workshop/event(N:M), the role of a participant in each workshop, and a table (letture) with access control for each participant in the workshop.

We create a unique QR code for participants/workshops. With this QR code, we can identify who went to which workshop and we can calculate for how many hours he remained.

But not all workshops need this in/out (entrata=1/2) value, for some are sufficient check who are present (entrata=0).

To print the final certificate for every participant in every event/workshop I try to populate the table `attestati_dati` with this query :

```
TRUNCATE attestati_dati; 
INSERT INTO attestati_dati 
(id_participant,id_event,id_workshop,id_role,id_attestato,ore_totali)  
SELECT * FROM 
(
   SELECT 
     p.id_participant AS id_participant,
     i1.id_event AS id_event,
     i1.id_sala AS id_workshop,
     r.id_role AS id_role,
     1 AS id_attestato,
     SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,
             i1.datalettura,
             IFNULL(i2.datalettura, i1.datalettura)))) AS ore_totali 
FROM
  letture AS i1
     LEFT JOIN
 letture AS i2 ON (i1.qrcode = i2.qrcode
     AND i2.datalettura > i1.datalettura
    AND i1.id_event = i2.id_event
    AND i1.id_sala = i2.id_sala
    AND i2.entrata = 2)
    LEFT JOIN
letture AS i3 ON (i3.qrcode = i2.qrcode
    AND i3.datalettura > i1.datalettura
    AND i1.id_event = i3.id_event
    AND i1.id_sala = i3.id_sala
    AND i3.entrata = 2
    AND i3.datalettura < i2.datalettura)
    CROSS JOIN
event_participants ep ON ep.qrcode = i1.qrcode
    AND ep.id_event = i1.id_event
    LEFT JOIN
participants p ON p.id_participant = ep.id_participant
    LEFT JOIN
roles r ON ep.id_role = r.id_role
    LEFT JOIN
events e ON i1.id_event = e.id_event
    LEFT JOIN
workshop_participant wp ON wp.id_participant = p.id_participant
    AND wp.id_workshop = i1.id_sala
WHERE
 i1.entrata = 1
     AND i3.datalettura IS NULL
     AND i1.id_Event = 52
GROUP BY i1.qrcode
UNION SELECT 
     p.id_participant AS id_participant,
     i1.id_event AS id_event,
     i1.id_sala AS id_workshop,
     r.id_role AS id_role,
     1 AS id_attestato,
    SEC_TO_TIME(0) AS ore_totali
FROM
 letture AS i1
     CROSS JOIN
 event_participants ep ON ep.qrcode = i1.qrcode
     AND ep.id_event = i1.id_event
     LEFT JOIN
 participants p ON p.id_participant = ep.id_participant
     LEFT JOIN
 roles r ON ep.id_role = r.id_role
     LEFT JOIN
 events e ON i1.id_event = e.id_event
     LEFT JOIN
 workshop_participant wp ON wp.id_participant = p.id_participant
     AND wp.id_workshop = i1.id_sala
WHERE
    i1.entrata = 0 AND i1.id_Event = 52
GROUP BY i1.qrcode , DAYOFMONTH(i1.datalettura)
) A;
```

I'd like to improve this query because this is the best I can do to solve this problem, but I think that is optimizable, especially in the group by/where/joins part.

Show Create table:

```
  CREATE TABLE `attestati_dati` (
 `id_attestati_participants` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `id_participant` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `id_event` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `id_workshop` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `id_role` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `id_attestato` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ore_totali` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_attestati_participants`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=25 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 1):

`e` and `wp` are not used, so remove the `LEFT JOINs to them.

Some composite indexes needed:

```
letture:  INDEX(id_event, entrata, qrcode, id_sala, datalectura)
ep:  INDEX(qrcode, id_event)  -- in either order
```

My suggested index for `letture` helps with all 3 uses of that table, and in different ways.  The order of the columns is critical, except that the first two can be swapped.

If `AND  i2.datalettura > i1.datalettura` is part of doing a "groupwise max", then it is especially inefficient.  [*This*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) discusses much faster ways.

`AND  i3.datalettura IS NULL` and its `LEFT JOIN` can probably be replaced by `NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 ... )`

The `CROSS JOIN` is technically an `INNER JOIN`, but since MySQL ignores `CROSS` and `INNER`, either of those works the same.  Ditto for plain `JOIN`.

The index recommendations come from looking at the `WHERE` clauses, and noting that nothing can be done about the `GROUP BY`.  More discussion [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

If you need to discuss this further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: Thanks, e and wp were used only in test.. i've forgot to deletes them.